# spring display wrong user input in form:input

Tags: java, spring

I have a model object in my controller.

let's say

```
Class person{
    Date birthDay;
}
```

when it is show in the form:input, if user input "aaaaa", of course it will fail and I just direct user to the same page and show them the error by putting the person to model again. but is there a way to keep the user wrong input at the input field?

```
<form:input path="birthday"/>
```

will just show empty because the binding fail. do I have to use a DTO object and make everything as string so wrong input can still be shown?

Comment: What is the exception message, what is your <form:form {commandName=??}> declaration? Do you register a date editor (is it sql or util Date) in the @InitBinder method?

Comment: usually what you'd do is show the "wrong" input in your error message. something like "aaaaa is not a valid date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate your situation. Can you provide more code? Mine exapme shows wrong input:

```
public class Person {

private Date birthDay;

public void setBirthDay(Date birthDay) {
    this.birthDay = birthDay;
}

public Date getBirthDay() {
    return birthDay;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {



@RequestMapping(value ="/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String edit(Person person, BindingResult result){

    return "person/edit";       
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(Person person, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "person/edit";   
    } else {
        return "redirect:person/edit.ss";
    }
}
```

Jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %> 
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="person">
Birth day: <form:input path="birthDay" /><form:errors path="birthDay" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```